# Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: arrays, struct, mapping, solidity, remix

I'm trying to create the contract using mapping struct and array. My goal is to allow companies to save several data in this system.

I can deploy it on Remix, but I faced the problem `Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert` when I wanna interact with the function `saveStandard`.

**However, if I get rid of the array part in the contract, it worked well.** Anyone know what happened?

The following is my code(with array)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage{
    
    struct UserInfo {
        uint index;
        string[] time;
        string[] source;
        uint[] emission;
    }
    
    mapping (string => UserInfo) public users;

    function saveStandard(uint input_material, uint weight, string memory input_time, string memory input_source) 
    public returns (string memory, uint, uint, string memory){
    
        uint id = users[input_source].index + 1;
        users[input_source].index = id;
        
        users[input_source].time[id] = input_time;
        uint Combustion = weight * input_material / 10;
        uint Process = weight * input_material / 10;
        users[input_source].emission[id] = Combustion + Process;
        
        return (input_source, Combustion, Process, input_time);
    }
    
    function search(string memory input_source) public view returns (uint, string memory) {
        uint id = 0;
        while (id <= users[input_source].index) {
            id += 1;
            return (users[input_source].emission[id], users[input_source].time[id]);
        }
    }
}
```

And the following is the one without array, this worked well.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage{
    
    struct UserInfo {
        string time;
        string source;
        uint emission;
    }
    
    mapping (string => UserInfo) public users;

    function saveStandard(uint input_material, uint weight, string memory input_time, string memory input_source) 
    public returns (string memory, uint, uint, string memory){
        
        users[input_source].time = input_time;
        uint Combustion = weight * input_material / 10;
        uint Process = weight * input_material / 10;
        users[input_source].emission = Combustion + Process;
        
        return (input_source, Combustion, Process, input_time);
    }
    
    function search(string memory input_source) public view returns (uint, string memory) {
        return (users[input_source].emission, users[input_source].time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
users[input_source].time[id] = input_time;
```

```
users[input_source].emission[id] = Combustion + Process;
```

It's these lines causing the revert.

You're trying to assign to `time[id]` array item, but the `id` index does not exist.

---

Your use case would fit better to use `mapping`s

```
struct UserInfo {
    uint index;
    mapping(uint => string) time;
    mapping(uint => string) source;
    mapping(uint => uint) emission;
}
```

Then you can simply assign value by the `id` key:

```
users[input_source].time[id] = input_time;
```

```
users[input_source].emission[id] = Combustion + Process;
```